# Fragment's and sub-Fragment's LinearLayouts aren't stretching to the entire parent size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm having an issue where my Fragment view inside a LinearLayout isn't streching to the parent's height and width. But it is a little bit more complicated since I have two Fragments inside that Fragment.

Here's the Activity's view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the parent fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:background="#FF00FF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mtg_player1_fragment_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mtg_player2_fragment_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the child (player) fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mtg_player_life_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mtg_player_life_count"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="140sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm adding the parent fragment like this (via clicking on a list item):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, fragment, newFragmentClass.getSimpleName()).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
```

And the children fragment like this (on the parent's `onViewCreated()`):

```
mPlayer1Frag = (PlayerFragment) getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.player1_fragment_wrapper);
if (mPlayer1Frag == null) {
  mPlayer1Frag = new PlayerFragment();
}
if (!mPlayer1Frag.isVisible()) {
  ((RoboSherlockFragmentActivity)getSherlockActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.player1_fragment_wrapper, mPlayer1Frag).commit();
}

mPlayer2Frag = (PlayerFragment) getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.player2_fragment_wrapper);
if (mPlayer2Frag == null) {
  mPlayer2Frag = new PlayerFragment();
}
if (!mPlayer2Frag.isVisible()) {
  ((RoboSherlockFragmentActivity)getSherlockActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.player2_fragment_wrapper, mPlayer2Frag).commit();
}
```

What I get is the following:

[image: Current (problematic) UI]

What basically happened is:

- The parent Fragment view didn't stretch vertically to fill the entire activity's view (no pink appeared);
- The TextView (green) didn't stretch to cover the children fragment layout (red/blue);

What I want to happen is for the parent UI to stretch in the entire activity, for the children to cover the entire parent and for the TextViews to cover the entire child. I could change it to use a single fragment (and may well do that), but I'd prefer if I could keep it this way, since it feels more organized :)

So, the question is, what am I doing wrong? Can't this be done using two fragments inside another?

Comment: How do you inflate the layouts for those fragments in the `onCreateView` methods?

Comment: In the simplest way possible:

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);`

Comment: Change it to `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, container, false);`(container is the second parameter of the `onCreateView` method) and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! After I answered your comment and looked into `onCreateView` signature and saw the `container` parameter there, I knew I was being stupid :)

Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `onCreateView()` method of a `Fragment` always inflate the layout file using the container parameter of that method like this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, container, false);
```

This way the inflated view will be given proper `LayoutParams` and it will behave as designed.